# How to change Connection String in Entity Data Model in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, connection-string, ado.net-entity-data-model

How to change Connection String in Entity Data Model in Visual Studio 2012

I Can Not Change Connection String in Visual Studio 2012
Help Me

Entity Data Model in Visual Studio 2012 Difference With Old Version

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the connection string from the app.config file, re-running the entity Data Model wizard will guide you to build a new connection.

From: [How should I edit an Entity Framework connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299775/how-should-i-edit-an-entity-framework-connection-string)

Comment: i'm change with programing Code