# Duplicate .Context.tt and .Context.cs created after Update Model From Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Background...may or may not be relevant:
I had a hard drive crash and just recently rebuilt my laptop and added an SSD while I was at it. As a result, one of my development projects was not on a different drive. It was originally in source control using TFS I re-bound the solution and projects and everything seemed find.

I then did some db changes and did an Update Model from Database in my edmx file. The update worked fine, except that in the process it created an additional *.Context.tt and *.tt file (the one with the green + next to them in the pic below). so now the compiler is complaining about the duplicate references.

The whole edmx to tt to cs process is black magic to me at the moment so I'm not sure how to clean it up. Can I just delete them? Will it recreated them on the next update? Ideally would like to know and address the root cause so it doesn't happen the next time.

[image: Source Explorer]

Comment: This Link might help you.
It Resolved the same issue i was facing.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36160965/8932378